# MySQL select from the same table but from different category with the same limit

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select from the same table

- articles where cat='Histoire' limit 12
- articles where cat='Cultures' limit 12
- articles where cat='Sujet Divers' limit 12

for this after searching i try the code bellow :

```
SELECT * FROM makale WHERE cat='Histoire' LIMIT 12
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM makale WHERE cat='Cultures' LIMIT 12
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM makale WHERE cat='Sujet Divers' LIMIT 12
ORDER BY id DESC
```

but the code dnt work
i get this erro :

```
Error
Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

Unexpected ordering of clauses. (near "LIMIT" at position 172)
SQL query: Copy Documentation

SELECT * FROM makale WHERE cat='Histoire' LIMIT 12 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM makale WHERE cat='Cultures' LIMIT 12 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM makale WHERE cat='Sujet Divers' LIMIT 12 ORDER BY id DESC

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM makale WHERE cat='Cultures' LIMIT 12
UNION ALL
SELECT' at line 2
```

can sameone show me the best way to do this
Thank you

Comment: Make it 'limit 3' and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Are cat and categroy the same thing? And what exactly do you mean by didn't work? Did it fail to syntax , or did it not produce the expected result

Comment: yes;
sorry i edit it now

Comment: Could you please add the error message. What do you mean with "don't work"?

Comment: i add it in the post

Comment: You have changed your code sample so that it does not match the error message..

Comment: @P.Salmon i write this "category" to know what i mean by "cat" :)

Comment: Thank you everyone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need subqueries:

```
(SELECT * FROM makale WHERE category = 'Histoire' LIMIT 12)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM makale WHERE category = 'Cultures' LIMIT 12)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM makale WHERE category = 'Sujet Divers' LIMIT 12)
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

You can also write this using window functions, but that is not your question.

Note:  This returns an *arbitrary* 12 rows for each category.  I'm leaving the code as is, because this answers the question you have asked.  But if you want a particular set of 12 rows, then you should use an `ORDER BY` in each subquery.

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon Linoff :)

Comment: @houssein ahmed: This picks 12 rows arbitrarily per category. Is this what you want? Or do you want them to be random (different result set each time you run the query)? Or do you want particular rows?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner i want exactly the last 12 row of each category

Comment: Then put `ORDER BY id DESC` before each `LIMIT`. (Provided the last rows have the highest IDs of course.)

Answer (score 0):

Limit cannot appear anywhere other than at the end unless in sub queries eg

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
CREATE TABLE T(ID INT, CATEGORY VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO T VALUES (1,'HISTOIRE'),(2,'HISTOIRE'),(3,'CULTURES'),(4,'SUJET DIVERS'),(5,'SUJET DIVERS'),(6,'SUJET DIVERS');

SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM T WHERE category='Histoire' LIMIT 2) A
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM T WHERE category='Cultures' LIMIT 2) 
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM T WHERE category='Sujet Divers' LIMIT 2) 
ORDER BY id DESC

+------+--------------+
| ID   | CATEGORY     |
+------+--------------+
|    5 | SUJET DIVERS |
|    4 | SUJET DIVERS |
|    3 | CULTURES     |
|    2 | HISTOIRE     |
|    1 | HISTOIRE     |
+------+--------------+
5 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```